# How to emulate MONITOR DETECT button press from Windows 10 display settings in Bash/PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, screen, monitor

I need to do display detection in windows script(powerShell is better for this I think?).

Which command will run the same thing which is running when I'm pressing button selected on the image below?
[image: Detect button]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force display detection in Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858844/how-can-i-force-display-detection-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into WASP.. you designate a window to look for and which button to press.

https://wasp.codeplex.com